# Hash that outputs a 8 characters

Tags: hash

I'm investigating a login system that exposes (probably) hashed passwords.

```
Password: HTSr0MF8Ou4liOCUayXHDg==
```

The password is stored in base64 format. When I decode it, I get random 8 chars regardless of password length.

The characters consist of random unicode characters. So, I know it's not an algo that I know like md5, sha, pbkdf etc.

Now, I don't want to crack it if it's a home brewed hashing algo, but if it's generic I want to find out what it is.

So, is there an algorithm known that

1. has 8 char fixed output
2. output consists of random unicode chars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I decode it, I get random 8 chars regardless of password length.

With the given base64 of length 24 you get 16 bytes. These 16 bytes are 8 unicode characters **only when interpreted as utf-16**. When interpreted as utf-32 it would be 4 characters and when interpreted as utf-8 it would be a variable number of (possible invalid) characters.

But nothing in the base64 or in any context you provide indicates that it actually has to be interpreted as utf-16, i.e. this is probably only an (unfounded) assumption you make. It is more likely that these are just 128 bits without any specific structure, i.e. no unicode characters at all.

> So, is there an algorithm known that a) has 8 char fixed output b) output consists of random unicode chars?

Again, the question is more if there is an algorithm which creates 128 seemingly random bits. Sure, it's a random generator. And another famous algorithm which has a 128 bit output is actually the MD5 hash.

Comment: Hey, you were right! It was in fact MD5. Thanks a lot!